# DumpGet::bgcor error

Tags: warning-messages, neural-networks

[image]

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"]; 

trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"]; 

testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
```

This is an example of the new function of the 11.2 version of Wolfram language. This is the link http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/measure-classification-performance.html?Product=mathematica.

What should I do to solve my problem？

Comment: Delete the resource object and try again. Also, please post code not images of code.

Comment: Thank you very much.